# Sorting ArrayList of ArrayList of double and string by the double in Java

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have an arraylist of arraylist which contains a string and an integer. It looks like:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList> l= {{1.02,"string1"},{0.33,"string2"},{1.15,"string3"},};
```

and I want to sort it by the order of the double number to look like this:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList> l= {{0.33,"string2"},{1.02,"string1"},{1.15,"string3"},};
```

I wrote this code but it doesn't work for me and I don't know where is the problem:

```
public void listSorting(ArrayList<ArrayList> l){
    int min=0;
    for(int i=0;i<l.size();i++){
        min=i;
        for(int j=i+1;j<l.size();j++){
            if((double)(l.get(i).get(0)) < (double)(l.get(min).get(0))){
                min=j;
            }
        }
        ArrayList temp=new ArrayList<>();
        temp.add(l.get(i));
        l.get(i).add(l.get(min));
        l.get(min).add(temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, you should be using [`Collections.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-) or [`List#sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-). Second, that's the wrong data type for that kind of data. Use an `ArrayList<YourCustomClass>`

Comment: Try using the debugger.

Comment: `.get(1)` what do you think that does?

Comment: You have to use comparator class for sort based on the object property.

Comment: @4castle how i use Collections.sort in this case ?
Ahamed how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made three mistakes:

- Index of `double` in your list is zero, not one,
- The inner loop needs to compare `min` item with item at index `j`, not `i`,
- When you swap two elements of type `ArrayList`, do not create a new array list.

Here is how you can fix your code:

```
for(int i=0;i<l.size();i++){
    min=i;
    for(int j=i+1;j<l.size();j++){
        if((double)(l.get(j).get(0)) < (double)(l.get(min).get(0))){
            min=j;
        }
    }
    ArrayList temp=l.get(i);
    l.set(i, l.get(min));
    l.set(min, temp);       
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/ax8nDP)

Comment: @Katty You need to be a lot more specific about the "doesn't work" part.

Comment: the arraylist is not sorted

Comment: @Katty `l.get(i).get(0)` should be `l.get(j).get(0)`.

Comment: no because we are in th 1st loop wich j is not defined